# Insert element at specific position is not happening

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to insert an element at specific position but code is throwing an error of

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

I am new in java so can anybody help me to correct my code. I know doing something wrong in `insertArr[i+1] = insertArr[i];` of insertPosition method. Any help will be count for good help.

My code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] insertArr = {10,30,20,40,60,50,90,70,80};
        Arrays.sort(insertArr);
        int arrLength = insertArr.length;
        System.out.println("At what position you want to insert");
        int pos = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What element you want to insert");
        int key = in.nextInt();
        insertPosition(insertArr,arrLength,pos,key);
        for(int num : insertArr){
            System.out.println(num);
        }
    }
    public static int insertPosition(int insertArr[],int arrLength, int pos, int key){
        if(pos > arrLength)
            return arrLength;
        for(int i=arrLength-1; i>=(pos-1); i--)
            insertArr[i+1] = insertArr[i];
        insertArr[pos-1] = key;
        return arrLength;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(int,%20E)

Like this:
insertArr.add(pos, key);

Comment: I am trying to do some coding practice so writing my own method for sorted array.

Comment: in addition to write own code I'd recommend you to *read* some standart code. Most of them contain comments, well-documented and care about many things you even didn't know before ;) At least, it helps me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that i is less than insertArray length and greater than zero.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] insertArr = {10, 30, 20, 40, 60, 50, 90, 70, 80};
    Arrays.sort(insertArr);
    System.out.println("At what position you want to insert");
    int pos = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What element you want to insert");
    int key = in.nextInt();
    insertPosition(insertArr, pos, key);

    Arrays.stream(insertArr).forEach(System.out::println);
}

public static void insertPosition(int insertArr[], int pos, int key) {
    if (pos >= insertArr.length)
        return;
    for (int i = insertArr.length - 1; i > (pos - 1) && i < insertArr.length -1; i--)
        insertArr[i + 1] = insertArr[i];
    insertArr[pos - 1] = key;
}
```

In java length of an array is immutable, when you are calling for an elements from index that does not exist, you are getting this exception. In order to avoid that in for loops you are checking if `i< array.length` or that i < array.length -2.

Secondly your method for insert can be simplified, like above.

Comment: It will not work if array is full already.Since method is `public` you could also add check if array is full and if yes, then create new or throw exception or just do nothing

Comment: after edit you could *lost* some values. It's worst practice. In order you can't insert element you should somehow signal about it but don't throw away!

Answer (score 0):

The length of an array is immutable in Java, You have to use a Collection of some sort such as a List/ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this block of code:

```
for(int i=arrLength-1; i>=(pos-1); i--)
    insertArr[i+1] = insertArr[i];
```

On the first iteration you're accessing `insertArr[arrLength]` which exceeds the last index of array. So you should start iterating from `i=arrLength-2;`

Comment: Correct but I don't think so I should start i=arrLength-2.

Answer (score 0):

First you must subtract 1 from the variable pos and verify if it is in the range of the length of the arrays.

Your code should look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] insertArr = { 10, 30, 20, 40, 60, 50, 90, 70, 80 };
    Arrays.sort(insertArr);
    int arrLength = insertArr.length;
    System.out.println("At what position you want to insert");
    int pos = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What element you want to insert");
    int key = in.nextInt();
    insertPosition(insertArr, arrLength, pos, key);
    for (int num : insertArr) {
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}

public static int insertPosition(int insertArr[], int arrLength, int pos, int key) {

    pos = pos - 1;

    if (pos >= arrLength || pos < 0)
        return arrLength;

    for (int i = arrLength - 1; i >= pos; i--) {
        insertArr[i] = insertArr[i];
    }
    insertArr[pos] = key;

    return arrLength;
}
```